# Create lines from a Blob field in ArcMap/Catalog or FME (or any other way)

Tags: arcgis-10.1, fme-form, polyline-creation

Is there some way to create lines from geometry stored in a Blob field? It's a SDE-database line feature class that has crashed in some way, but I can still get the raw data and the feature class works in a third party application. No, I can't recover the database from a backup, because it turns out our IT department only stores backups 7 days.

The said third party application reads it's data from a view made of the data table and geometry table. This view I have exported to a regular file geodatabase (to be on the safe side with experiments). So, I need to somehow extract the geometry data from the Blob field, so I can recreate the lines. I'm having a hard time finding anything like this on Google.

There's also a field named ENTITY, and one named NUMOFPTS. I'm guessing these have got something to do with the Blob field (named POINTS).

Comment: This question is related to one of my other [Questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48835/error-opening-feature-class-from-sde-which-can-be-opened-in-another-application/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.2/concepts/geometry/representations/compressed.htm#Logical) is documentation on ArcSDE Compressed Binary :

> Internally, all ArcSDE coordinates are 64-bit positive integers
>   between 0 and 2147483647 (if defined using a 32-bit coordinate
>   reference) or between 0 and 9007199254740990 (if defined using a
>   64-bit coordinate reference). Note that 64-bit coordinates are
>   actually limited to a 53-bit range so that no information is lost when
>   converting to or from double precision floating point representation.
>
> Because real-world coordinates are often neither positive nor integer,
>   ArcSDE data requires an offset distance (a false origin) to ensure
>   numbers are positive and a minimum resolution multiplier (called the
>   scale) to convert real numbers to integers. Offset distances are
>   specified in the same units as the data. The scale can be any positive
>   value up to 2147483645.
>
> The scale can be any positive value up to 2147483645 if using a 32-bit
>   coordinate reference, and up to 9007199254740990 if using a 64-bit
>   coordinate reference.

**Update**

Before taking this approach, I recommend trying to fix your database.  It that fails, try using the [C API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/capi.htm) to retrieve geometry.

Comment: Thanks! Although I can't find anything in there to help me extract the geometry from my Blobs. Have any ideas?

Comment: @Bananapa Did you look at the "physical representation" section?  Really, though, before taking this approach I recommend trying to un-crash your database.  What 3rd party app is able to read the data?  Perhaps that app uses the [SDE C API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/capi.htm).

Comment: I contacted the makers of the third party application, and we were able to export the geometries. Since our IT department didn't store the backups longer than 7 days, backup was not an option.